# ASP.net Core React Template Route Attribute on Controller cannot prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Using the dotnet cli I created a project based on the asp.net react template.
Issues I do have with the controller class and customizing the `Route()` attribute on the class.

**One important note: Routing with prefix does work, when using the asp.net webapi template, but does not work in the react teamplate.**

This works just fine:

```
...
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TransactionController : ControllerBase
{ ...
```

Whenever I use something different to `[Route("[controller]")]` like

`[Route("api/[controller]")]` or even

`[Route("someBetterNaming")]`
it doesnt work.

Is there some other place I have to configure the routing?

In the official tutorial there is nothing else mentioned.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/)

TransactionController.cs

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    
    namespace asp_react.Controllers;
    
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]  // working
    // [Route("api/[controller]")]  // not working
    public class TransactionController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetTransaction()
        {
          return Ok("get success");
        }
    }
```

Programm.cs below

```
// Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

Still trying to familiarize with the file structure and learning to know which files are critical for configuring the project.

Comment: Can you post a full minimal example + error and http return codes?

Comment: Could you please share your full `controller` along with your `configuration`  like `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs` in case of `dotnet 6` and what `prefix` you are trying to implement. So that it could be easier to explain

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved? Do you still need any assistance on this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would like to start with your below statement

> In the official tutorial there is nothing else mentioned?

The document or tutorial you are following is a basic tutorial which
explain overall view of how you can build a asp.net project and how to add
controller generally. But if you would like to more details on
Asp.net 5/6 Routing then you should follow [this official document
to know details anatomy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

> Is there some other place I have to configure the routing?

For explaining, above statement there are few things should be clear before,

**Firstly,** as per your question below:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]  // working
[Route("api/[controller]")]  // not working
```

**Secondly,** if you are trying to use all three route attribute together in one controller then I would say, maybe you still have some confusion about the structure of controller routing. You have to follow either a pattern like below:

***"Pattern:1"***

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    
    public class VehicleFilterController : ControllerBase
    {
    }
```

***"Output:1"***

[image]

***"Pattern:2"***

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/VehicleFilter")]

public class VehicleFilterController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

***"Output:2"***

[image]

So these are valid pattern and will work as expected.

**Note:**

For above two route URL Pattern should be `https://localhost:7132/api/VehicleFilter`

**Thirdly,**  if you would try all together like below :

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Route("api/VehicleFilter")]
public class VehicleFilterController : ControllerBase
{
   
}
```

There would be no error on compile time but while you would call the `route` in run time it would encounter an error. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:`  which means you
cannot point to multiple route attribute in single controller. As
you can see the screen shot below:

[image]

**Finally,** Now come back to your question "Is there some other place I have to configure the routing?"

If you would like to configure multiple conventional routes then you can add "Multiple conventional routes" reference on your `Program.cs` you can [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#multiple-conventional-routes):

[image]

**Note:** In addition, I would highly suggest you to have a look on [**Attribute routing for REST APIs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis) which would be very helpful for you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I updated my post to make it a little clearer. It does work as you describe when using the asp.net wepabi template but not when using the react template. I did not wanted to use multiple routes.,

Comment: It doesn't sounds good while changing the question context, because here efforts and time matters, anyway, `"but not when using the react template"` how did you created the project? what exactly not working? Did you get any specific error?

Comment: Using the dotnet cli I created a project based on the asp.net react template. `dotnet new react` I dont get an error, the endpoint is just not reachable .

Comment: I guess it has something todo specificly with the react template. There are some more things like swagger etc. I tried succesfuly with the webapi template but do not work with the react template. Documentation on the react template is quite bad though.

Comment: I only hit the endpoint via postman/insomnia. By intention I isolated this issue from the react part.

Comment: Still from postman it doesn't hit the controller? what kind of project you have taken while creating the soluton? could you please confirm what happend when you replace `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();` with `builder.Services.AddControllers();` in `program.cs` file

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the effort. I think I have to dive a little deeper into ASP.NET and react, there are just too many weired cases between the templates.

Comment: No problem,  you can do that, let me know if any further assistance required for my side additionally if you think that my efforts is helpful you could accept my answer so community members can get similar issues resolved